# SQL Order By issue with UNION

Tags: sql-order-by, union

I have two SQL queries which using `UNION`.

```
SELECT 
   studentID 
FROM 
   Student 

UNION 

SELECT 
   courseName 
FROM 
   Course;
```

If I want to order the result by `courseName`, how can I do that?

If I try the following it gives me error.

```
SELECT 
  studentID 
FROM 
  Student 

UNION 

SELECT 
  courseName 
FROM 
  Course 
ORDER BY 
  courseName ;
```

Comment: Are the students studying each other? Otherwise this has got to be nonsense! And that's not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the columns have to be the same in both unified `SELECT`'s. I'm not sure, but it doesn't look like that in your case (because of `studentID` and `courseName` - sounds like `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR`).

However, if that's the case, just put it as a sub-select and sort the result:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT studentID AS col
          FROM Student 
         UNION 
        SELECT courseName AS col
          FROM Course)
 ORDER BY col;
```

**p.s.** as Stephan pointed out correctly you don't need the sub select here:

```
SELECT studentID AS col
  FROM Student 
 UNION 
SELECT courseName AS col
  FROM Course                                
 ORDER BY col;
```

Reason for this is the way how UNION works.

**p.p.s.** see some Fiddles here: [ORACLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b9b8/2) and [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2a14/2).

Please note: `AS` is typical for MySQL. If you use ORACLE remove it.

Cheers!

Comment: +1 but there's no need for a tmp table since you could have added `ORDER BY col` at the end of the `UNION`

Comment: Good catch, wasn't aware of this and will improve it. Thanks!

Comment: Both `studentID` and `courseName` are type of `varchar`. So in that case do I need to do any changes than you suggest.

Comment: No, nothing to do in that case. `VARCHAR` sounds like ORACLE - just remove the `AS` keywords in that case. See Fiddles for further experiments too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT 
   'student_id' as type,
   studentID as value
FROM 
   Student 

UNION 

SELECT 
   'course_name' as type,
   courseName as value
FROM 
   Course  
ORDER BY
    type,
    value
```

**BUT** keep in mind ,as Trinimon well pointed out , that on value column you will have only strings (studentID will be converted to string)

Comment: +1 This is an interesting idea. You have a `;` after `Course` - that shouldn't be there. BTW implicit type conversion won't work for ORACLE (needs `TO_CHAR(..)` instead)

Comment: Thx, i removed the `;` I'm not very familiar with ORACLE so i will take your word for granted :D but in mysql the conversion is done by default to the type that can accommodate both types (string in this case)

Comment: Yes, made some small Fiddles: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b9b8/2 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2a14/2

Answer (score 0):

First break the query up so it does not give an error:

```
SELECT 
    studentID
FROM
    Student


SELECT 
    courseName 
FROM 
    Course
```

The first part give an id, which is an integer or guid, the second give a string

The union operator combines two queries with the same column types.

What you probably want is a JOIN. look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp and here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp